# Securing the credentials for a user provided service in bambo.yml

Tags: devops, cloud-foundry, bamboo, bamboo-specs

I created a user provided service using below command in bamboo,yml

```
cf cups my-service -p '{"url":"https://some-url.com","username":"admin","password":"admin"}'
```

As these credentials are visible in the enviromental variables of the application and may leak somewhere , I changed the above command to use credhub as shown below

```
cf create-service credhub default my-service -c '{"url":"some-url.com","username":"admin","password":"admin"}'
```

Here I used credhub and  but this command is also placed in the bamboo.yml file , so the credentials are still open to app developers .
What can be done differently to secure these credentials and not to put them directly in bamboo.yml ?

Answer (score 1):

Think how would you do it without bamboo.yaml. Maybe you should put credentials to secret variable (if variable has secret or password part at name Bamboo will encrypt it) and then reference it at your command

Comment: Yes thats one of the probable options which can be implemented. .

Comment: Additionally, encrypt the password using `/bamboo/specs/encryption.action` so that it's not in cleartext even in the yaml specs. See https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-specs-encryption-970268127.html

Answer (score 0):

There are few options:

1. You can put whatever you want into the properties that you set on a ups i.e. user provided service. It could be plain text or encrypted text. If you put encrypted text, your application will need to understand how to decrypt the text so that it can be used. The platform just passes through the properties that you set on the user provided service.
2. You can use either spring vault  or external vault instance with hashicorp service broker https://github.com/hashicorp/cf-vault-service-broker to retrieve/store credentials within your application in a secure way
3. Another option could be to store the configuration in cloud config like Spring Cloud Config but Vault is still be recommended for credentials. You can then run it as a server and provides the configuration to your running applications. It might be overhead though for small project.